# Handling reverse-engineering related questions

Tags: discussion, answers, downvotes

I recently started to participate more actively on StackOverflow community, answering people's questions, so I want to handle things properly.

Is there a specific way to deal with questions that include reverse-engineering? As an example, someone told that was trying to reverse-engineer a specific site, trying to scrape data. I assume that person is not doing it for the sake of debugging otherwise he/she would have access to internal data.

Should this kind of question be down-voted? Or maybe it's better to try to understand what kind of data the user is looking for, give some pointers about public APIs that could help?

I do think one should take code/data copying ethics in consideration, but if it's not a constraint in the community guidelines, I'll just ignore the question and move on.

EDIT:
Adding to the link provided on marking this question as duplicate, I also found this one on comments, that provides good discussion about the situation as well:

[Dealing with questions of nefarious intent](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3528/dealing-with-questions-of-nefarious-intent)

Comment: Just noting the obvious that usually reverse engineering is not directly related to programming, and would definitely be a better fit at [reverseengineering.se].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Should this kind of question be down-voted?

No, there's no reason to downvote a question *only* because it's about reverse-engineering or web scraping. As long as it's a good, well-researched, on-topic question, there's no reason to close-vote either.

> Or maybe it's better to try to understand what kind of data the user is looking for, give some pointers about public APIs that could help?

That's certainly an option. I'd put that in a comment if you're only going to tell them a public API is available for the information they're looking for. If you're willing to give a full answer that shows how to access that API, that's even better.

> I do think one should take code/data copying ethics in consideration...

Yes, we definitely should do that, and it's ok to mention it in your answer. People should be polite about rate limiting themselves when they're scraping someone else's data (for example), so there's nothing wrong with including a warning with your answer, or even illustrating how to do it in code. But we should also assume that someone asking questions has good intentions unless we have a very good reason to believe otherwise. So please don't downvote someone just for asking about web-scraping or reverse-engineering. Take a moment to educate them instead.