# Asking questions about how a website works

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions

Would it be a valid question on Stack Overflow to ask about how a certain website works?

The question would be about the [Yahoo Finance echarts](https://finance.yahoo.com/echarts?s=YHOO%20Interactive#%7B%22allowChartStacking%22:true%7D) - How the graph populates and more specifically how the box in the top left corner of the graph (picture below) gets updated as you move your mouse over the graph data without refreshing the page. Like where the `open` `close` `low` `high` etc. values come from, and whether or not I would be able to print that to the console or somehow grab that data from the website for each x-axis value.

[image]

Comment: Related: [Handling reverse engineering related questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/306258)

Comment: I doubt that such questions are welcome on SO, especially since you can simply look at the source code of websites yourself.

Comment: @Floern spent the last hour looking at the source code and haven't been able to figure anything out

Comment: You could use some in-browser web developer tool (e.g. FireBug for Firefox) to inspect the content. Then you will see that the graph is an SVG (including the top left box) generated dynamically with JavaScript.

Comment: @Adjit in that case the source code is either obfuscated (you likely won't get anyone willing to deobfuscate it) or you just lack the html/javascript knowledge to understand it. In the second case you could probably pick out small pieces of code you don't understand (even still you have to try to research it first) but the whole site is a bit out of scope for a question. Also you are asking too many things (out of scope of a single question). So as your question is right now, I don't think it would be appropriate.

Comment: If you have specific code that you've tried that isn't working, post it on SO with a specific problem statement. If you have an idea of how to implement it but are not sure of the specifics, Programmers.SE is a better site. If you have code that works and you just want a second pair of eyes to look it over, CodeReview.SE is the proper site. No matter where you post your question, make sure it follows the rules for whichever site you're posting to. In particular, make sure your question is specific enough. ("How does this general thing work" is not specific enough, in most cases.)

Comment: @GordonAllocman some of the code is obfuscated, however, at the end of it they have a big statement saying anyone who wants to use this is more than welcome to. I see it is generated dynamically with JS, but I don't know where it is getting the data from. I am just trying to see if I can print those values to the console, wherever they are in the page

Comment: Short answer is no, we don't want these types of questions.

Comment: Any such question is WAAAAY too broad.

Comment: No, such a question is not appropriate at SO. It's far too broad in scope. This site is for **specific questions** about actual problems you're facing, and figuring out how someone else's web pages work is not a problem you're facing; it's a wish you have to use the same functionality, and there's no **specific question** being asked.

Comment: This is an XY problem. "How do I glean chart information from a stock graph" should really be "How do I find an API for stock information". Both of which aren't topical at Stack Overflow.